# How do I keep a function running as a background process after redirect()?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, background-process

I have this in my controller:

```
function foo() {
    // my code
    redirect(site_url('competitor/main'), 'refresh');
    $this->foo2();
}

function foo2() {
    // upload a file
}
```

How do I keep `foo2()` running after using the `redirect()` method?

The reason I want to call `foo2()` after `redirect()` is because I want to save upload time. When a user uploads a file at `site_url('competitor/main')` it will go to `foo()` function, then redirect immediately back to `competitor/main` page and `foo2()` will run in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter's `redirect()` function `exit`s after sending the location header. So, call the function before redirecting.

```
$this->foo2();
redirect('competitor/main', 'refresh');
```

Note: No need for `site_url()` here, the redirect function will add it if you use a relative URL.

I'm not sure what `foo2()` does, but this looks a little iffy...

If for some reason you can't do that, then send the header with native PHP.

```
header("Refresh:0;url=".site_url('competitor/main')); 
$this->foo2();
exit;
```

---

> When user upload file on `site_url('competitor/main')` it will go to `foo()` function then redirect immediately back to competitor/main page and `foo2()` will run in background process.

This probably isn't the way to handle uploads, as you will have no way to deal with errors. There are a couple of other ways I can suggest:

- Upload to another URL, process the file, then redirect to the page of your choice (with a status message if you wish)
- Have your upload form post to an `<iframe>`, which will keep the page in it's current state.
- Advanced: Use javascript to upload the file with an XMLHttpRequest/AJAX. There are a [number](http://www.plupload.com/) of [scripts](http://www.uploadify.com/) [available](http://www.swfupload.org/) for [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax%20upload).

Comment: I don't think this is true. I've tried this where foo() { sleep(30); } and it definitely blocks page load.

Comment: @Ben That is expected, but if you calll `redirect()` first then `foo()` won't run at all.

Comment: That's true but if you put it before it does not run in the background - hence not solving the problem. See my suggestions below.

Comment: Right, my solution was simply to not run it in the background, which is why I suggested plupload/swfupload/uploadify etc. I wanted to point out the basic error in the OP's code too. Your answer seems to avoid the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to keep the upload running and redirect that same window to another location. @Wesley Murch's example would start the refresh immediately but the page would only fully load once the upload had completed not saving any time on the user end.

You can run php in the background using shell_exec but not for uploads. I'd suggest creating a popup window for the upload with Javascript if you want it to continue in the background.

Otherwise try something like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It won't make the upload any faster but it will show clear upload progress to the user and make for a nice experience.